# Colouring the Marbles around the Circle

Tags: combinatorics, coloring

Let us say, we have an integer $n$ that satisfies $n \geq 3$. An integer $m \geq n + 1 $ is called n-colourful if, given infinitely
many marbles in each of $n$ colours $C_1, C_2, \dots , C_n$, it is possible to place $m$ of them around a circle so that in any group of $n + 1$ consecutive marbles there is at least one marble of colour $C_i, i = 1, \dots , n $.
Prove that there are only finitely many positive integers which are not n-colourful.
For more clarification, without loss of generality, if we fix the number of colours as $n$, we can find $k$ integers $m_1,m_2,\dots,m_k$ such that $\forall i: m_i$ are not n-colourful. I believe, the idea is to find such function $f(n)$ that bounds the values of not n-colourful integers and, therefore, we would prove that there exists finite amount of them.
Consider this trivial example when $n=3$:
Integer $m=5$ is not 3-colourful because according to pigeonhole method I am able to select a colour $C_j$ such that there is at most one marble of colour $C_j$. Given that, I will choose other four marbles ($n+1=4$ consecutive marbles) without including the colour $C_j$. Therefore, $m=5$ is not 3-colourful.
Integer $m=6$, however, is 3-colourful because there exists an arrangement of colours in the circle by ascending order of the colour indices: $C_1,C_2,C_3,C_1,C_2,C_3$. In this case, integer $m$ is 3-colourful because no matter what $n+1=4$ neighbouring marbles I would choose, I would select at least one marble of each color.
Note that if we choose to colour relatively large number of $m$ marbles by uniformly distributed $n$ colours, $m$ is most likely to be n-colourful because then the number of consecutive marbles $n+1$, that need to be observed, is much smaller than $m$.